# R Alternatives to a for loop for searching through a large dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, performance, for-loop

The goal here is to identify and count if the entries in column b have  matching entries in column a with a range of +/-1 (or as required). A simplified version is provided:

```
a <- c("1231210","1231211", "1231212", "98798", "98797", "98796", "555125", "555127","555128")
b <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "1231209", "98797", "555126")
df <- data.frame(a, b)
```

I merged this data in a dataframe to simulate my actual dataset, converted them to numerics and wrote the following function to get my desired output. (note: column a need not be part of the df, but can be a separate list I suppose?)

```
df$c <- mapply(
function(x){
    count = 0
    for (i in df$a){
        if (abs(i-x) <= 1){
            count = count +1
        }
    }
    paste0(count)
},
df$b
)
```

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1231210 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1231211 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1231212 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 98798 | 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 98797 | 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 98796 | 6 | 0 |
| 7 | 555125 | 1231209 | 1 |
| 8 | 555127 | 98797 | 3 |
| 9 | 555128 | 555126 | 2 |

While this appears to work fine for the trial dataset, my actual dataset has over **2 million** rows which means 2M^2 iterations? (still running after 3h) I was wondering if there is an alternate strategy to tackle this, preferably using base R functions only.

I'm quite new to R and a common suggestion is to use vectorization to improve efficiency. However, I have no clue if this is possible in this case when looking at the examples provided on the net.

Would love to hear any suggestions and feel free to point out mistakes. Thanks!

Comment: `df$c <- sapply(df$b, function(x) sum(abs(a - x) <= 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data is quite large, `outer` and `lapply` approaches will be quite slow (for `outer` you need 14901.2 Gb of RAM). I suggest using `data.table`

```
require(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

dt[, id := 1:.N] # add id as maybe you have duplicated values
setkey(dt, id)
dt[, b1 := b - 1L]
dt[, b2 := b + 1L]
x <- dt[dt, on = .(a >= b1, a <= b2)] # non-equi join
x <- x[, .(c = sum(!is.na(b1))), keyby = .(id = i.id)]
dt[x, c := i.c, on = 'id']
dt
#          a       b id      b1      b2 c
# 1: 1231210       1  1       0       2 0
# 2: 1231211       2  2       1       3 0
# 3: 1231212       3  3       2       4 0
# 4:   98798       4  4       3       5 0
# 5:   98797       5  5       4       6 0
# 6:   98796       6  6       5       7 0
# 7:  555125 1231209  7 1231208 1231210 1
# 8:  555127   98797  8   98796   98798 3
# 9:  555128  555126  9  555125  555127 2

dt[, id := NULL][, b1 := NULL][, b2 := NULL] # remove colls
```

p.s. check that `a` and `b` are converted to integers before...

Comment: Many thanks for sharing this approach! It is amazingly fast (took a couple of seconds to process). On the other hand, my initial mapply for-loop method would have taken 10 days according to pbmapply.

Answer (score 1):

why are vectors `a` and `b` characters? They should be `numeric`:

```
a <- c(1231210,1231211, 1231212, 98798, 98797, 98796, 555125, 555127,555128)
b <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1231209, 98797, 555126)
```

You can simplify by using only one loop and vectorization:

```
unlist(lapply(b, function(x) sum(abs(a-x) <= limit)))
```

where `limit` is variable describing allowed difference. For `limit <- 1` you get:

```
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 2
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `colSums` + `outer`?

```
transform(
  type.convert(data.frame(a, b), as.is = TRUE),
  C = colSums(abs(outer(a, b, `-`)) <= 1)
)
```

## output

```
        a       b C
1 1231210       1 0
2 1231211       2 0
3 1231212       3 0
4   98798       4 0
5   98797       5 0
6   98796       6 0
7  555125 1231209 1
8  555127   98797 3
9  555128  555126 2
```